# Load CSV files into Sql table with different number of columns and column names using Script Task in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, multiple-columns

I want to load csv files into an SQL table using a Script Task in SSIS which have similar column names but not exactly the same and the number of columns also vary.

I am currently using the script below from this useful [blog](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2015/06/load-text-csv-files-to-table-when.html) which checks whether the exact column name exists and if it does, loads it into the table, however, it will fail if the column name doesn't exist. Is there a way to use the LIKE operator to search the column name from the csv file in the sql table? If it finds it, load the data into the table and if it doesn't find it, ignore the column.

Script:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        string delimiter = Dts.Variables["$Package::Delimiter"].Value.ToString();
        string TableName = Dts.Variables["$Package::TableName"].Value.ToString();
        SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
        myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)
        (Dts.Connections["ADOConn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);


        //Reading file names one by one
        string SourceDirectory = Dts.Variables["$Package::SourceFolder"].Value.ToString();
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory);
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {

            // MessageBox.Show(fileName);
            string columname = "";

            //Reading first line of each file and assign to variable
            System.IO.StreamReader file2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);



            //Writing Data of File Into Table
            int counter = 0;
            string line;

            System.IO.StreamReader SourceFile =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
            while ((line = SourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                if (counter == 0)
                {
                    columname = line.ToString();
                    columname = "" + columname.Replace(delimiter, ",");
                    //MessageBox.Show(columname);
                }

                else
                {
                    // MessageBox.Show("Inside ELSE");
                    string query = "Insert into " + TableName +
       "(" + columname + ") VALUES('" + line.Replace(delimiter, "','") + "')";
                    //MessageBox.Show(query.ToString());
                    SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
                    myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                counter++;

            }

            SourceFile.Close();
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

 }
}
```

Thanks,
J

Comment: You can query the sys.columns of the table you are loading and use a like operator for the column you are uploading and use logic to load to that column. A possible issue would be if you have multiple columns that meet the like criteria.